# Получение конкретного значения из querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, input, value, queryselectorall

возник такой вопрос:

```
function addPaper(
        title,
        authors,
        participationForm,
        abstractFile,
        fullPaper,
        paperId
    ) {
        const element = document.createElement("div");

        element.innerHTML = `
            <button class="accordion">${title}</button>
            <div class="panel">
                <p>Authors: ${authors}</p>
                <p>Participation Form: ${participationForm}</p>
                <p>Abstract File: ${abstractFile}</p>
                <p>Full Paper: ${fullPaper}</p>
                <button class="delete">Delete</button>
                <button class="upload">Upload</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="paperId" value="${paperId}">
            </div>
        `;

        paper.append(element);
    }

    addPaper(1,2,3,4,5,6);
    addPaper(7,8,8,10,11,12);
    addPaper(13,14,15,16,17,18);
```

Здесь я создаю элементы на странице, у которых есть скрытый инпут со своим валуе. Дальше я хочу делать запросы на сервер для которых мне необходимо значение этих инпутов, но не всех, а конкретного.

```
let paper = document.querySelector(".accordionPaper");

    paper.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        let accordion = e.target.closest(".accordion");
        if (!accordion) return; // Клик был не внутри аккордеона? Прервать функцию.

        let panel = accordion.nextElementSibling;
        let isVisible =
            (panel.style.display || getComputedStyle(panel).display) != "none";

        panel.style.display = isVisible ? "none" : "block";
    });

    paper.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        let paperId = paper.querySelectorAll("input");

        if (e.target.classList.contains("delete")) {
            alert(
                `$Id of this paper: ${})} `
            );
        } else if (e.target.classList.contains("upload")) {
            alert("you click upload button");
        }
    });
```

Как мне передать value у нажатого мной paper?

Comment: `id="paperId"` нельзя делать больше одного элемента с одним индификатором.

Comment: @OliverPatterson исправил, но вопрос всё ещё актуален

Comment: `$Id of this paper: ${paperId[0]} ` получится?

Comment: И почему бы кнопкам просто не дать data-id и его считывать в `e.target`

Comment: @OliverPatterson дело в том, что я буду брать данные с сервера и вручную обрабатывать это не получится, нужно решение, при котором программа будет сама понимать какой пэйперАйди ей тягать

Comment: Так в инпут можешь подставить при создании элемента, а в data-id нет?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение было найдено:

1. Вместо инпута я на кнопки, которые у меня есть добавил дата-атрибут data-id, в который передавал необходимое мне значение

```
function addPaper(
        title,
        authors,
        participationForm,
        abstractFile,
        fullPaper,
        paperId
    ) {
        const element = document.createElement("div");

        element.innerHTML = `
            <button class="accordion">${title}</button>
            <div class="panel">
                <p>Authors: ${authors}</p>
                <p>Participation Form: ${participationForm}</p>
                <p>Abstract File: ${abstractFile}</p>
                <p>Full Paper: ${fullPaper}</p>
                <button data-id="${paperId}" class="delete">Delete</button>
                <button data-id="${paperId}" class="upload">Upload</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="paperId" value="${paperId}">
            </div>
        `;

        paper.append(element);
    }

    addPaper(1,2,3,4,5,6);
    addPaper(7,8,8,10,11,12);
    addPaper(13,14,15,16,17,18);
```

2. Я при нажатие на необходимую мне кнопку я записывал значение data-id в переменную.

```
paper.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        let paperId = e.target.getAttribute("data-id");

        if (e.target.classList.contains("delete")) {
            let i = confirm("Вы уверены, что хотите удалить доклад?");
            if (i) {
                alert(`This is paperId: ${paperId}`);
            }
        } else if (e.target.classList.contains("upload")) {
            alert(`This is paperId: ${paperId}`);
        }
    });
```

Я не уверен в грамотности этого подхода, но пока вроде всё работает.
За помощь спасибо @OliverPatterson